# How to change Method of Object in python

Tags: python

I write a python file like :

```
class A(object):
    def update(self, str):
        pass

    def say(self, str):
        print "I update: " + str

def fun(obj, str):
    obj.say(str)

a = A()
import types
setattr(A, "update", types.MethodType(fun, None, A))
a.update("hello")

b = A()
b.update("world?")
```

It change behave of class, the object b have been changed. but, I want to only change object a.
How to change Method of Object in python?

Comment: on a side note you should avoid using variable names for built in types. str is a built in type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```
 a.update = lambda x: fun(a, x)
```

Comment: hi, Aapo Kyrola, if I have two objects a and b, and I set fun to a and b both. They both have same update behave

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the class method, while you want to set only the method bound to some instance.

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def a(self): pass
... 
>>> MyClass.a = lambda x: x
>>> MyClass.a
<unbound method MyClass.<lambda>>
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.a
<bound method MyClass.<lambda> of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x1d7fed0>>
```

Changing the `a` method at class level changes also the `a` methods of all instances.

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def a(self): pass
... 
>>> b = MyClass()
>>> b.a = lambda x: x
>>> MyClass.a
<unbound method MyClass.a>
>>> b.a
<function <lambda> at 0x1d88938>
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> c.a
<bound method MyClass.a of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x1d8d110>>
```

Changing the `a` method of an instance does not change the method of the class or other instances.